# Under what condition can we have $\partial_y \int f(x,y) \,dx=\int \partial_y f(x,y) \,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Is there a $C^1$ function $f:R^2 \to C$ such that
>   $(1)$ $f(\cdot , y)\in L^1(x)$ for $a.e. \,\,y$
>   $(2)$ $\partial_y f(\cdot ,y) \in L^1(x) $ for $a.e. \,\, y$
>   $(3)$ $\partial_y \int f(x,y) \,dx  \neq \int \partial_y f(x,y) \,dx$ for $y \in E \subset R$ with $\mu(E) \gt 0$

By the energy method in PDE , we usually need to deal with the term $(u,\partial_t u)$ . And we want to deduce that $$2(u,\partial_t u) =\partial_t (u,u)$$
But under what condition does the above equation valid ?

Comment: there are some theorems about that, by example take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)